# Connecting Text using line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created my resume using latex and now I want to connect experiences using a line similar to linkedin (Reference Attached). I am fairly new to latex and have referred to multiple resources and most of them don't work for this scenario. I understand that tikz is probably going to be used here but haven't been able to get it to work yet.
Any solution would be appreciated

[image: Reference]

Comment: Please add the code of your resume so far (simplified and anonymized, but still compilable), otherwise it is not really possible to advise how you can achieve this output.

Comment: I am using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz

Comment: It's better to add the relevant code to your question here for future reference, in case the template gets moved or deleted in Overleaf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the class is not available in TeXLive, I'm not posting complete code here. But the `tcolorbox` `skins` library provides a built-in way of doing this.

Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{itemize}{blanker, borderline west={2pt}{8pt}{black}}
```

The relevant parameters to play with are the width of the line (here set to `2pt`) and the offset from the left edge of the environment (here set to `8pt`).

Here's a complete sample using `article` class and `enumitem` to compact the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{itemize}{blanker,borderline west={2pt}{8pt}{black}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item An item
\item Another item
\item Another item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Here's some sample output from the example document provided with the template:

[image: output from Overleaf]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. A simple and concise solution.
Thanks